# Are Unity Rotations & Torque both measured in degrees of rotation per second?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

Are Rotations & Torque both measured in degrees of rotation per second?

I am trying to match the rotation speed of two objects. One is rotating using torque, while one is rotating using a transform. According to the Unity docs and the forum posts I've read, they can both be measured in degrees per second if the transform rotation is multiplied by Time.deltaTime.

[Rotate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html):

> The implementation of this method **applies a rotation of zAngle degrees**
> around the z axis, xAngle degrees around the x axis, and yAngle
> degrees around the y axis (in that order).

[Add Torque as a VelocityChange:](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddTorque.html)

> ForceMode.VelocityChange: Interprets the parameter as a direct angular
> velocity change **(measured in degrees per second)**, and changes the
> angular velocity by the value of torque. The effect doesn't depend on
> the mass of the body and the simulation step length.

I have a GameObject set to rotate at a given speed per second, and a Rigidbody with angular drag set to 0 that is given a torque value. Theoretically, these two objects should be rotating at the same speed:

```
[SerializeField] private GameObject Object1;
[SerializeField] private Rigidbody Object2;
[SerializeField] float RotationSpeed = 1f;


public void Start()
{
    Object2.AddRelativeTorque(Object2.transform.up * RotationSpeed, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
}

public void Update()
{
    Object1.transform.Rotate(Object1.transform.up * RotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.Self);
}
```

However, they rotate at very different speeds. Is there something I'm missing here about how this should work?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the word `degrees` includes the meaning of degree and radian, but I can confirm that the unit of the `torque` parameter is **radian/second** when `ForceMode.VelocityChange` is given. And the result will be affected by `maxAngularVelocity` and `angularDrag` properties.

BTW there is a problem in your code, since you used `AddRelativeTorque` and `Space.Self`, you shouldn't use a global vector for the first parameter if you want the object to be rotated along its y axis.

```
Object2.AddRelativeTorque(Vector3.up * RotationSpeed * Mathf.Deg2Rad, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
Object1.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * RotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.Self);
```